# How to set space between contained divs?

Tags: html, css

The inner divs will be thumbs that are being continuously added and eventually wrap to next row.

The space between divs should be 20px.
I want four divs in one row.

Two constraints:

1. Ideally no flexbox space-between, due to last row looking weird with only two divs.
2. Adding margin only between inner divs not a good option (unless there’s an easy way to do this for dynamically added content?).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```css
#outer {
  width: 460px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/christiank/pen/gOYQZzE)

Comment: `#outer > div:nth-child(n+2) { margin-left: 20px }`, oh and what's the point of the float here?

Comment: "*I want four divs in one row.*" - will new elements be added four at a time? If not, what should happen in the event of one, two or three new elements being added?

Comment: @DavidThomas Elements don't have to be added four at a time. In any case elements should wrap to next row. Yazans and Ibrahims solutions are great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use `nth-child(4n)`

```
.inner {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.inner:nth-child(4n){
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/abozanona/pen/RwbqmZb

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope, it will work.

I used the CSS grid. By using `grid-template-columns`, I have declared how four children elements of outer ID take the same area in a row. After that, I used `grid-gap: 20px` for giving space between four children block.

```
#outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this code should be tried, explain what it does, how it works to solve the problem. Try and teach people instead of throwing blocks of unexplained code at them. Yes, I know how/why it works, but there's a very good chance that others looking for this answer won't.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Good to hear and you are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```css
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

Read a reference here: [css-protips](https://github.com/AllThingsSmitty/css-protips#use-not-to-applyunapply-borders-on-navigation)

Comment: As there can be more than 4 items, wrapped on their own row, this won't work

Answer (score -1):

You could use a margin and avoid the last one:

```css
.inner:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There can be more than 4 (wrapped), hence this won't work